# How to add arbitrary or custom metadata in MP4?

Tags: ffmpeg

The MP4 muxer in `ffmpeg` only allows [certain metadata](https://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php/FFmpeg_Metadata#QuickTime.2FMOV.2FMP4.2FM4A.2Fet_al.) by default. I would like to add:

```
com.android.model: Mi 10 Pro
xyz: +22.9835+113.3621/
com.android.version: 1
com.android.manufacturer: Xiaomi
```

How can I add this with `ffmpeg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-movflags +use_metadata_tags` to set arbitrary metadata for MP4:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -metadata xyz="+22.9835+113.3621/" -metadata com.android.version=1 -metadata com.android.manufacturer="Xiaomi" -metadata com.android.model="Mi 10 Pro" -movflags +use_metadata_tags output.mp4
```

Comment: Note that when using this switch the built-in ffmpeg supported MP4 container meta information stops working correctly. Namely tags listed here https://kodi.wiki/view/Video_file_tagging