# embed timestamps into MP4 container

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, fmp4

I have a fragmented MP4 file. It was created by recording a stream from a digital camera. Is there some way to store timestamps inside the container for later display on the web interface?

Comment: For using FFmpeg to add your timestamp metadata, try the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67068734/2057709. You need to give more information for a better answer... (1) Is it one timestamp like video's **creation date/time**? Or is it multiple times in one video (for every frame, for every second)? (2) What is your _"on the web interface"_? Did you write some code to use MSE to play each fragment in a video tag? If yes, it means you are capable of processing the MP4 bytes so maybe just attach your timestamps at the end of each fragment (as `udta` box entry), then extract it on playback

Comment: PS: If your timestamps are stored in a text file then an easier alternative is to just have your timestamps converted into a subtitle file. Then your _"For later display on the web interface"_ becomes displaying subtitles that are the timestamps...

Comment: @VC.One I guess we could store one timestamp in metadata and then calculate timestamps for each frame just by adding pts to that time. I like your idea of using udta box for each fragment, because we do use MSE and basically have access to that information. I like your idea with subtitles too, I think I should be able to store them as a separate track. Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @VC.One Do you possibly know what would the best approach to display that time in Safari using HLS? We do not have access to the boxes inside fmp4 anymore, because there is no MSE on iphones. We use video tag and EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME tag inside HLS but do not know how to extract it from the video tag.

Comment: I don't use Safari but since the M3U8 is a text file maybe extract the date from the file (using fileReader in JS, if the m3u8 is on same server as the player page, or else just use PHP's readFile to skip any CORS issues).